# Subgroups of Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

This might seems to be a stupid question...
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension (infinite extension). Denote its Galois group to be $G=Gal(L/K)$

I want to ask: (1), Is every subgroup be in form of $Gal(L/M)$ for some extension of $M/K$, as in the finite Galois extension case?

(2), Can a normal subgroup of $G$ being non-open as well as non-closed?

(3), Krull topology says that {$Gal(L/M)$, where $M$ runs over all finite Galois extension of $K$} forms a open neigh basis of 1. Is any open normal subgroup be in form of $Gal(L/M)$, $M$ finite and Galois over $K$?

Comment: For the (3), I think it's true, since in topological group, open subgroup must be closed. And by Galois correspondence theory, it must be that form.

Comment: (1) and (3) are answered in any text on infinite Galois theory. As for (2), the answer is yes. You can find an example in Milne's [Field and Galois Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/FT0.pdf), Proposition 7.26. (The other questions are also answered in this text).

Comment: (1): Look at the subset $\langle Frob_p\rangle\subset\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F}_p/\mathbb F_p)$.